# How to send email with html table output in email

Tags: android, debugging, whitespace, html-table, html-email

I am working on ArrayList, i want to send email type of html format with arraylist content, 
i am trying to write array content in BufferedWriter Like..

```
mOrderList = db.getOrderList();
    // getting all arrayList content
     for (int i = 0; i < mOrderList.size(); i++) {
     no = mOrderList.get(i).getId();
     itemName = mOrderList.get(i).getOrderItemName();
     unit = mOrderList.get(i).getOrderUnit();
     qty = mOrderList.get(i).getOrderQTY();
     rate = mOrderList.get(i).getOrderRate();
     amt = mOrderList.get(i).getOrderAmount();
     try {
         mbufferWriter =new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/data/data/com.sample.category/abc.txt"));
     mbufferWriter.write("<html><h4>Customer Order List</h4>" + "<body> <table>"
                + "<tr><th>Item No</th>" + "<th>Item Name</th>"
                + "<th>Unit</th>" + "<th>QTY</th>" + "<th>Item Rate</th>"
                + "<th>Amount</th></tr>");
     mbufferWriter.append("<tr><td>" +no+"</td>");
     mbufferWriter.append("<td>"+itemName+ "<td>");
     mbufferWriter.append("<td>"+unit+ "<td>");
     mbufferWriter.append("<td>"+qty+ "<td>");
     mbufferWriter.append("<td>"+rate+ "<td>");
     mbufferWriter.append("<td>"+amt+ "<td></tr>");
     mbufferWriter.append("</body></table></html>");
     mbufferWriter.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }//for
```

and trying to send an email like this but it gives error...

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[] { "abc@gmail.com" });
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "sample email sending");

                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.toHtml((Spanned) mbufferWriter));

                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                    // startActivity(i);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(EmailActivity.this,
                            "There are no email clients installed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

can any one help me fix this problem ..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Post your logcat also.

Comment: Besides writting your whole html text into the BufferWriter , you can simply write it into a String and then you can set it as `Html.toHtml(<your String here>)`.

Comment: @Grishu as you say i am trying with stringBuffer...Thanks..

Comment: Still not working ....<table tag not working>.....

Comment: `Html.fromHtml` doesn't handle `<table>` tags, just certain ones for text formatting. If you want to display complete HTML you need to manage each text with the either `<br>` tag or `<p>` or `&nbsp;` space tag as per your needs.

Comment: Any Other way to display table except <br>,<p>,&nbsp; ...

Comment: AFAIK its the only way.

Comment: But what if I want to have full HTML support?

Answer (score 0):

`Html.toHtml` doesn't support `<table>`. It only supports basic tags like `<b><u><i>`...

Answer (score -1):

Use a `pre` tag to create a table:

```
 mbufferWriter.write("<html><h4>Customer Order List</h4>" + "<body>" + 
        "<pre> " +
            "  Item No    Item Name    Unit     QTY   Item Rate     Amount" +
        "</pre>");
```